# Can you have too many asserts (in Python)?

Tags: python, validation, assert

Lately, I've been adding `asserts` to nearly every single function I make to validate every input as sort of a poor-man's replacement for type checking or to prevent myself from accidentally inputting malformed data while developing.  For example,

```
def register_symbol(self, symbol, func, keypress=None):
    assert(isinstance(symbol, basestring))
    assert(len(symbol) == 1)
    assert(callable(func))
    assert(keypress is None or type(keypress) is int)
    self.symbols_map[symbol] = (func, keypress)
    return
```

However, I'm worried that this goes against the idea of duck typing, and that I might be going too overboard or constricting myself unnecessarily.  Can you ever have too many assert statements?  When's a good time to stop?

Comment: Side note: You should make use of duck typing (don't check for the type, check for "abilities" like available methods). Also, that `return` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: The real question is: does it help you or does it make your work more difficult.

If lot of asserts will help you track errors - do lot of asserts in your code. 

If you need static typing why you chose Python for your project?

Comment: @Niklas I like the return, though.  It makes me happy inside :D

Comment: @Secator I really like the dynamism of Python, but on occasion wished it was a bit stricter on occasion so I can catch errors earlier.  This is just my attempt to reconcile that urge.  I don't really want full static typing, though.

Comment: @Deflect: Heh, that's an argument :P By the way, I agree with Secator, if you need type safety but don't want to miss dynamic elements, try Haskell or Scala or something similar. You won't get anywhere near their degree of type safety in Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I only use `assert`s if they provide far better diagnostics than the error messages that I would get otherwise.  Your third assert

```
assert(callable(func))
```

might be an example for such an assert -- if `func` is not callable, you will get an error message at a completely different line of code than where the actual error is, and it might not be obvious how the non-callable object ended up in `self.symbols_map`.  I write "might" because this depends on the rest of your code -- if this is the only place where `self.symbols_map` gets updated, the assert might also be unnecessary.

The first and last assert definitely are against the idea of duck-typing, <s>and the second one is redundant.  If `symbol` isn't a string of length 1, chances are that `self.symbols_map[symbol]` will raise a `KeyError` anyway, so no need for the asserts.</s>

The last assert is also wrong -- `type(keypress)` cannot be `None`, and type checks should be done with `isinstance()`.  There might be very specialised applications where you cannot allow subtypes, but than the check should be performed with `type(x) is int` instead of `type(x) == int`.  Checking for `None` should be done by `x is None`, not by `type(x) is NoneType`.

You should probably write a good set of unit tests -- they will be far more useful than the asserts, and might make almost all of your asserts redundant.

Comment: Hm, if `symbols_map` is a dict, it shouldn't raise a `KeyError`.

Comment: @NiklasB.: Could you explain this a bit further?

Comment: @Sven: Sorry, I meant that the line `self.symbols_map[symbol] = (func, keypress)` will not raise an error if `symbol` does not fulfill the constraints OP seems to have been placed upon the key.

Comment: @NiklasB.: You are completely right, but I didn't get that from your last comment. :)

Answer (score 3):

Asserts in your code are not nearly as useful as unittests.  Do more of the latter, less of the former.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that assert statements are stripped whenever Python generates optimized bytecode! Since that is the case in most production environments, assert statements may not be used to validate input.
In fact, I came to the conclusion that I can't use them for anything at all if I can't rely on them being executed. So if I need to check some condition, I use "if ... raise ..." instead, and if I just want to test my code, I write unittests.